# How do I get the wear leveling data for my HGST HCC545032A7E380 SSD?

Tags: linux, ssd, smart

`smartctl -a /dev/sda` won't show what I need. `grep -i` matches none of "wear", "life", "left", "level".

It does offer information on `Raw_Read_Error_Rate, Throughput_Performance, Spin_Up_Time, Start_Stop_Count, Reallocated_Sector_Ct, Seek_Error_Rate, Seek_Time_Performance, Power_On_Hours, Spin_Retry_Count, Power_Cycle_Count, G-Sense_Error_Rate, Power-Off_Retract_Count, Load_Cycle_Count, Temperature_Celsius, Reallocated_Event_Count, Current_Pending_Sector, Offline_Uncorrectable, UDMA_CRC_Error_Count, Load_Retry_Count`.

On top of the initial `Device Model, Serial Number, LU WWN Device Id, Firmware Version, User Capacity, Sector Sizes, Rotation Rate, Form Factor, Device is, ATA Version is, SATA Version is, Local Time is, SMART support is, SMART support is` list.

Yes,

```
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

Comment: By hybrid I mean classic rotational HDD with SSD cache. Bit it just a guess with lack of real model name.

Comment: smartctl -Ai /dev/sda more compact and contain smart attributes and device info.

Comment: Try look something like "Total LBAs Written". `grep -i wri`

Comment: All information should be in the question body.  Unnecessary commentary will be flagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to find specification for HGST HCC545032A7E380.

[image]

https://www.electronicsdatasheets.com/manufacturers/hgst/parts/hcc545032a7e380

This say it not a ssd, but ultrathin 2,5" HDD.

PS. Shame for Hitachi. Impossible to find specification on hgst.com

Comment: So take a screenshot of the information that says that.